# How to modify table name dynamically using INSERT statement in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in which I am inserting in a table using Insert statement i.e.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Development$Call]
```

I want to use the same stored procedure for the production system.

Is it possible to change `Development$Call` to `Production$Call` *dynamically* or by *programming* in the stored procedure?

If I run the same stored procedure in development or production machine the text is replaced automatically in the insert statement to Development or Production

Kindly suggest if it is possible. And if possible then how I can achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: It's a bad practice to have different schema in different environment.

Comment: The store procedure is same just I have to replace the machine name.. so the storeprocedure is correctly executed on the machine it's being run by replacing XXX with correct machine name in XXX$Call

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping table like the below.

```
MAPPINGTABLE

**ServerName    Environment**
PRODServer  PRODUCTION
DEVServer   DEVELOPMENT
```

Add this snippet to your stored procedure. @@Servername returns the current servername. Pass this to your mappingtable to get the environment.

```
IF (SELECT Environment from MappingTable where ServerName=@@SERVERNAME)='DEVELOPMENT'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Development$Call]
....
ELSE
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Production$Call]
....
```

Comment: I have 7 servers so in this solution I will have a very long stored procedure just repeating insert statement and then copying this stored procedure on all servers..

Isn't it possible to just replace XXX$Call with the @Servername

Comment: @user271762 yes, it is possible but it requires creating a temp variable with the T-SQL and running `EXEC()`. You are far better off separating your dev and prod environments into separate databases with the same names for all the tables.

Comment: Yes I have separate databases for dev & prod and other systems. I just need to run the same script on all of them. by replacing the server name with table in the insert statement.

Comment: @MrAnderson Can you give an example.. Thank you

Comment: @user271762 It is good that you have separate servers, but as the rest of my comment stated, having your tables named the same across environments will fix your issue. Why call your table `[Development$Call]` why not simply `[Call]`?. You will know if it's dev/prod by which server it is in.

Comment: @MrAnderson it's not only dev and prod I have total 7 different servers where I have to run this script so I need to have [Development$Call]  syntax because it is the requirement of the #CUSTOMER and there are 7 machines setup like this. I need to run the same script on all machines  such that the table name is replaced by the exact machine name on which its running.